# How to say "give"

Tags: word-choice

あげる would be the word that means "give". But what if I were to give someone something that I am not sure if it will benefit the person or the person might not like. In this case, あげる would probably be a very bad word. For example:

ケーキをあげる - give you cake

あげる doesn't seem to be appropriate here because that person might be allergic to cake or might not like cake. Is there a better word to use in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

あげる is not a very sensitive word to refer to giving someone something when casually spoken in the receiver's absence. But as you are concerned, using あげる is not always a good choice for telling "give to you" in person.

> *what if I were to give someone something that I am not sure if it will benefit the person or the person might not like*

In this case, I would ask them first:

> ケーキとかどうですか？ *What do you say to a cake?*
>   ケーキとかいりますか？ *Would you like a cake?*

とか is meant to be an extra cushion word here, somewhat like "perhaps". You can replace it with は for simpler grammar.

If what you want is a value-neutral word for some objective description, you can use [渡す](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%B8%A1%E3%81%99/) "to hand, transfer".

Comment: Thanks. Can I directly say ケーキ渡す instead of ケーキあげる to mean "give you cake" in a neutral tone?

Comment: @Newbie That'd most likely result in a response: "for what?" In actual speech 渡す is usually used in a situation like leaving something to them for a while.